# lcov - create and use gcad files while running

Tags: linux, gcc, gcov, lcov

I want to use lcov in some tests I run.
Tests are not part of the binary I compiled with lcov.
I noticed that lcov create gcda files only after binary is ended.
The problem is that I want to run several tests without restarting the binary and still be able to pause before a new test to collect data from gcda.
Do you know how to make lcov to create gcda files while running?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the project we call 
 __gcov_flush();